# Get the current admin login details in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am in the process of creating a external external script that will pull out the information about the current admin who is login. im new to magento and still learning how to use their apis. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about the user connected on the admin panel

```
$userArray = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getData();
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session'); 
$userId = $user->getUser()->getUserId();
$userEmail = $user->getUser()->getEmail();
$userFirstname = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
$userLastname = $user->getUser()->getLastname();
$userUsername = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
$userPassword = $user->getUser()->getPassword();
```